# How to generate codes using prost in rust?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I don't know how to generate codes using `prost_build`

I have read the documents, but they don't give a detailed command of generating code.
I type `cargo build` but no codes are generated.

my `build.rs`

```rust
extern crate prost_build;
fn main() {
    prost_build::compile_protos(&["src/items.proto"],
                                &["src/"]).unwrap();
}
```

my `Cargo.toml`

```rust
[package]
name = "snazzy"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["xxx <xxx@xxx.com>"]
edition = "2018"
build = "build.rs"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
bytes = "0.4"
prost = "0.5"

[build-dependencies]
prost-build = { version = "0.4"  }
```

my `items.proto`

```rust
syntax = "proto3";

package snazzy.items;

message Shirt {
    enum Size {
        SMALL = 0;
        MEDIUM = 1;
        LARGE = 2;
    }
    string color = 1;
    Size size = 2;
}
```

my file tree:

```
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── items.proto
    └── main.rs
```

No build error but I can't see where the generated codes are.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, this isn't very well explained in the docs, and this is because of the way build scripts work. Well, partly.

Your protobuf implementations are under `target/{yourArch}/build/{yourCrateName}-{hash}/out`.

This would be extremely hard to get to if it wasn't for environment variables. The important part of the documentation is the following snippet of code highlights the inclusion:

```
pub mod items {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/snazzy.items.rs"));
}
```

This includes the file available at `OUT_DIR` (the directory specified above, filled in automatically during compilation) and the name of the protobuf implementation (your package name in the protobuf file), and makes all its content structs available under `crate::items`.

It makes sense for the files to reside in the build directory, as they are a build artefact. Code generation in the `src` folder of your crate would lead to chaos, both when it comes to version control and project sanity (you'd have a duplication of information, and the protobuf implementation, provided that it is sane, isn't *that* important to you. The functional blueprint is, however).

Comment: I ignored the last code piece of the documentation. Thanks for your detailed explaination!

Comment: You have to also put the build.rs and lib.rs in the project's root directory, not `src`. I guess the doc assumes you know, but I'm a n00b

Comment: I have both `build.rc` and `lib.rc` in the `src` and it works perfectly. If it does not, let's start another question and figure the error together